# How to translate one language to another using java code

Tags: java, google-translate

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.api.translate.Language;
import com.google.api.translate.Translator;

public class Translation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {                
        // Translate a single English String to French
        Translator translator = new Translator();
        System.out.println("Saying goodbye in French:");
        System.out.println(translator.translate("goodbye", Language.ENGLISH, Language.FRENCH));

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't this work? What happens when you run it?

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/1370/java-internationalization-i18n-example-tutorial

Comment: Saying goodbye in French:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.translate.Language.getLangCode()Ljava/lang/String;
 at com.google.api.translate.Translator.constructLangPairQuery(Translator.java:230)
 at com.google.api.translate.Translator.constructQueryURL(Translator.java:247)
 at com.google.api.translate.Translator.translate(Translator.java:72)
 at com.inndata.services.Translation.main(Translation.java:14)

Comment: I've never worked with google api's but I think either you're missing a jar library or you don't understand the API fully, you can look at this question for the exception you get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695340/java-nosuchmethoderror

Answer (score 3):

First, Google translate API is a paid service: https://cloud.google.com/pricing/

Second, you have to create your own API key and use the key in your app: https://console.developers.google.com.

The code I am using:

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
AndroidJsonFactory jsonFactory = AndroidJsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
Translate.Builder builder = new Translate.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
// need this, otherwise you get warning
builder.setApplicationName("Give a name");
Translate translate = builder.build();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// I only add one char to the list
list.add(String.valueOf(word[0]));
Translate.Translations.List request = translate.translations().list(list, "en").setKey("<your_api_key>");
String result = request.execute().getTranslations().get(0).getTranslatedText();
```

Note: don't know the reason yet, I always got the same error if I use my android API key: "com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden", and the reason says "ipRefererBlocked", but it is fine if I use my Browser Key. Hope someone else can figure out the reason.