# Akka-ZMQ subscriber creation error (poll)

Tags: akka, zeromq, jzmq, akka-zeromq

I successfully created publisher but failed to create subscriber by using the following:

```
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("System");
        ActorRef subscriber = system.actorOf(new Props(Sub.class),   "subscriber");    
        subscriber.tell(new MyActor("CharlieParker", 50, 25), subscriber);
    }
    public class Sub extends UntypedActor 
    {
        ActorRef subSocket = ZeroMQExtension.get(getContext().system()).newSubSocket(
        new Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:1237"),
        new Listener(getSelf()), Subscribe.all());
    }
```

Got this error:
Uncaught error from thread [System-akka.zeromq.socket-dispatcher-7] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[System]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.zeromq.ZMQ$Poller.poll(J)J
    at akka.zeromq.ConcurrentSocketActor$$anonfun$10.apply(ConcurrentSocketActor.scala:180)
    at akka.zeromq.ConcurrentSocketActor$$anonfun$10.apply(ConcurrentSocketActor.scala:179)
    at akka.zeromq.ConcurrentSocketActor.akka$zeromq$ConcurrentSocketActor$$doPoll(ConcurrentSocketActor.scala:197)
    at akka.zeromq.ConcurrentSocketActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ConcurrentSocketActor.scala:46)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you are either missing or having the wrong version of zeromq-scala-binding on your path.

Which version of akka and zeromq are you using?

Comment: I have built zeromq-3.2.2.tar(http://download.zeromq.org/zeromq-3.2.2.tar.gz) and jzmq-master(https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq). Copied generated zmq.jar to the project classpath and libraries seems to reside on my local: Hakan-MacBook-Pro:lib Hako$ ls | grep libjzmq
libjzmq.0.dylib
libjzmq.a
libjzmq.dylib
libjzmq.la
Hakan-MacBook-Pro:lib Hako$ ls | grep libzmq
libzmq.3.dylib
libzmq.a
libzmq.dylib
libzmq.la

Comment: I have built this one also (after I read your comment): https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq and the problem still exists.

Comment: So now I see. Do you have the jzmq bindings in your classpath? Akka relies on the zeromq-scala-bindings available here https://github.com/valotrading/zeromq-scala-binding and they are not a drop in replacement for each other.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't have to build any of these by yourself. If you just add the akka-zeromq artifact as a dependency to your maven or sbt project you should get all the necessary java/scala libraries.

Comment: I have the same exact issue... with ZeroMQ 3.2.2 and trunk built for the dll and jar. No issue :-(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same type of error while trying to work with akka-zeromq and did some investigation on the subject. So the situation is the following: the error message states that it didn't find a method `long poll(long timeout)` in the class ZMQ.Poller (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945908/259395) answer for the error message interpretation). This happens because of the following reasons

1. Akka is built with zeromq-scala bindings.
2. zeromq-scala is supposed to be compatible with jzmq , but unfortunately it's not at the moment because in scala bindings you have method `long poll(long timeout)` while in jzmq you have `int poll(long timeout)`

To overcome your problem locally you either have to rebuild Akka with zmq.jar, or use a quick and dirty workaround: change the return type for the method `poll(long timeout)` in jzmq ZMQ.Poller class and rebuild the java bindings. For more details and bindings compatibility  discussion take a look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/akka-user/GnPHIR0HK3g)

However there is a global java/scala bindings compatibility problem, but it's outside of the scope of your question.