# Error connecting to Google Calendar

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to connect to Google Calendar using Oauth 2.0. Two days ago worked fine, however now throws an exception: "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.util.Strings.isNullOrEmpty(Ljava/lang/String;)Z".

I'm using google-api-java-client-1.14.1. (I have got "google-http-client-1.14.1-beta.jar" in my libraries).

The problem only occurs in deployed version, everything works fine when I run the applicaction on my local machine.

Code:

```
public GoogleCredential conexion(String email, String scope) { 

    GoogleCredential credential =null;
    try{

        // Build service account credential.
        credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(scope)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(file))
        .setServiceAccountUser(email)
        .build();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


return credential;

}


public int function(){
    GoogleCredential sa = serviceAc.conexion("user@mail.com",CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);

    Calendar service = new Calendar(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), sa);//   here throw the exception
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` you trying to call a method that is available in Compiletime classpath and isn't available anymore in Runtime classpath check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945908/1460591)

So, No such error for method (actually you should post the full error here) this method isn't not supported anymore in runtime so all you have to do is to search this method and its supported new Class which you will find in a new Jar