# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass while using Hibernate Annotation and Maven

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Maven and web technologies. I am getting error

"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration; "

while doing CRUD operation using hibernate .  Can some one please look into my pom.xml and suggest what am I missing ( Server is Tomcat)  :

```
 SessionFactory sf = new 
 Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Inbox.class).
                 addAnnotatedClass(UserControl.class).
                 addAnnotatedClass(UserData.class).
                 addAnnotatedClass(UserData.class).buildSessionFactory(); 

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
       </dependency>  

<!-- Apache Commons FileUpload --> 

       <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
      </dependency>

<!-- Apache Commons IO --> 

       <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Interpreting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945862/interpreting-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-message)

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson It is not an exact duplicate. And you remove the `hibernate` tag, so `hibernate` related guys will not be able to notice that question and help :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have dependencies for different Hibernate versions **5.2.11.Final** and **3.2.6.ga**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>
```

If you use an application server, for example Wildfly, you will need to disable Hibernate module that bundled with Wildfly.